# How to present a Image in Xamarin from Database

Tags: c#, android, database, image, xamarin

I have uploaded a image from an ASP.NET website to the database (an interface to update news on the Xamarin.Android app).

The Image is uploaded as `byte[]`, and the target DB has the datatype `varbinary(Max)`. The image is saved.

When I show it on the website as is just for test (asp.net webpage)

The code is... This works

```
........(a stored procedure that return value).............
byte[] bytes = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar(); // Returnera ett värde
String stringBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64,"+ stringBase64;
```

But I want to know how I can make a web service and what datatype type the Xamarin.Android wants. A code example please.

I can't figure this out. =/

I should be able to use some of the code in the web service example. And how it would be placed in this with C# code.

```
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
 imageView ???????????????????????????
 mainlinerlayout.AddView(imageView);
```

This was my attempt:

```
  byte[] bytes = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar(); // Returnera ett värde

  // I'm unsure about this 2 lines but example on internet wants it to be Converted to tobase64string, and memorystream wants byte[]
  String stringBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64);

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
```

So

The Xamarin.Android Load

That call the webservice that gets the image from the database.

A full code please. This is one of the last part i need to

Get right before I can go forward.

Comment: You could try using jgoldberger's advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372917/xamarin-save-image-varbinary-into-xamarin-android-sqlite-c-sharp#comment93646533_53372917

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if it works. Just to be clear are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

```
String stringBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64);

Image image = Image.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
return image;
```

Comment: I will check that
Im using Xamarin.Andorid 
But for everyone include myself please answer for both =)