# Xamarin Save Image varbinary into Xamarin.Android sqlite c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to learn how to save image with SQlite on the Android.

Can someone help me with example to save Image to the Sqlite and then get it to the Imageview with C#.

Comment: generally most don't store image data in a database but rather store the URL to the image in the database. So once you have the image saved on your device as a file, get a url to the file and then store that in SQLite. Or see this forum post for using BLOB type to store image data in database directly: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/242056/#Comment_242056

Comment: Thanks i will check that, do you have any how to show it again? Sqlite to imageview